# Low pass filter (?) in Thorlabs PDs

Tags: circuit-analysis, photodiode, optoelectronics

[image]

What is the purpose of this circuit in all Thorlabs PDs? It looks like a second order low pass filter to me, but shouldn't it be two resistors in that case?

Comment: It's not a 2nd order filter.

Answer (score 2):

It filters noise on the photodiode bias. You see different variations on that circuit (2C/2R, etc) in various circuits depending on how noisy the bias voltage is expected to be and how much photocurrent is required.

In this case the second resistor will be the source output resistance, which is often several ohms anyway.